# Can a workflow be used to update a column's choice field values?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, choice-field, sharepoint-designer

For example, I have a topic column that has 3 choices with the ability for user to "fill-in" their own topic. What i'd like to know is it possible to use workflows (or some OOB functionality) to update that choice list with any new values. The reason I ask is because I do not have access to Central Admin and will not be able to implement any coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "Topic" column look up column or Choice column?Ideally you should be using look up column

Comment: It's a Choice column. How would you use a lookup column in this?

Comment: You can create a List called something like say  "TopicsList" and create a look up column in the list where you want that "Topics" column which actually gets data from "TopicsList". When user want to add new  values to the "Topics" column options, user can add a new item to that "TopicsList" and that new item will appear in  the options for "Topics" column.

Answer (score 4):

I've done what Unnie describes above before. First you create a list and populate it with all your choice values. Then you configure your list people will add items to by creating a new column of type lookup that points to the list you just created using the Title column. You set it to allow fill in votes.

Then in a workflow, you check if a fill in option was entered. If so, you create an item in the lookup list. I took it a step further to capture the ID that is returned by that item creation operation to then clear the fill in value and set the current item lookup field to that newly created item.

Comment: Lookup column doesn't have fill in option.. Also how do you check in the workflow if the selection is from the drop down or its a fill in option.